# How to Calculate Tezos Fees

Tags: fees

I am programatically calculating fees for transactions.

AFAIK, bakers by default adhere to the following fee calculation:

```
fees >= (minimal_fees + minimal_nanotez_per_byte * size + minimal_nanotez_per_gas_unit * gas)
```

where

```
minimal_fees = 0.000 1ꜩ (100µꜩ)
minimal_nanotez_per_gas_unit = 100nꜩ/gu (0.000 000 1ꜩ/gu)
minimal_nanotez_per_byte = 1000nꜩ/B (0.000 001ꜩ/B)
```

([Source](https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/003_PsddFKi3.html?highlight=fees#baker))

Today, I had a [transaction which timed out in the mempool](https://carthage.tzkt.io/ooC8DzaAaFAPEg2JKdMyNvJMn2trtVakAfcsszmeChyaGem4qf4). The transaction used 66754 gas units and 234 bytes of storage.

Based on the above, I think that the proposed fee of 0.00701XTZ should have been sufficient to get included in a block:

```
minimal fees =                     .000001
gas fees     = 66745 * 100nꜩ/gu =  .006676  (rounded up)
storage fees = 234 * 1000nꜩ/B   =  .000234 
----------------------------------------------
total        =                     .00701
```

Why was this transaction not included in a block?

Comment: If you want to compare, https://tzkt.io/opP2A3NnAPwioSHfVcjv6B6Vji5HKF6ruRsJyEVUWDk1x8S7Xy5
0.00701 is crazy high for a fee, almost 4x the minimum of 0.001792. I believe the storage minimum is 257. You might want to look for more examples of calling contracts to see what their fees/params are set.

Comment: AFAIK 257 bytes is the fixed cost for origination of a contract. This is simply an invocation.

The gas is expensive, which makes sense. This is a multi-contract call that is updating a big map and serialization/deserialization and contract calls are expensive.

I was able to send successfully in this transaction: https://carthage.tzkt.io/ooXP3djDo1ccchKkcytxk2X7y7foa7uGz3gaKDv1AoAVoyDwQnY which applied with:
gas = 66754
storage = 234

So I believe those values are correct. I just don't know how to back out the actual fee in XTZ from them.

Comment: You don't. Gas doesn't have relationship with the txn fee.
https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/psa-do-not-quote-gas-cost-in-tez/1618
You can specify max gas for every operation and keep the minimum fee and still have success. Gas is just a limiting factor to prevent runaway contracts.

Comment: Okay, so it "technically" doesn't but in practice it does.

If this wasn't true, then why did this operation not apply? The same exact operation applied with a higher fee.  This operation sat in the mempool for 20+ minutes before I overwrote it.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

'Storage' (the bytes on chain) is burned and isn't related to the fee.

The `minimal_nanotez_per_byte` refers to the size of the transaction itself when serialized to bytes with a signature.

Comment: can you explain more about fee calculation? or link any documents?