# How to define (calculate) fee parameter for transfer?

Tags: transactions, fee

Is there a way to calculate the transaction (transfer) fee only with RPC or eztz.js lib? Either, the only the user can define this parameter?

I used only gas price for eth likeness blockchains before to estimate fees.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Calculate Tezos Fees](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2733/how-to-calculate-tezos-fees)

Comment: Gas in Tezos is not the same as Eth Gas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use taquito for this. (https://tezostaquito.io/docs/estimate)

[Operation cost for invoking smart contract](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/operation-cost-for-invoking-smart-contract)